# Angular CLI Deployment не работает правильно

Tags: angular2, angular

Используя source из папки dist после выполнения `ng build --prod` не работает ссылки если их вбивать в браузер только по / можно и не работает `OwlDateTimeModule`.
Как это исправить ?

Comment: `не работает ссылки если их вбивать в браузер только по / можно и не работает OwlDateTimeModule`, `Angular CLI Deployment не работает правильно`. Если честно, то это какой-то набор слов. Опишите проблему. Что вы делали? Какой результат ожидали? Какой результат получился? Ну и *запятые, они, тоже, очень, необходимы,,,,*.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Я использую ng-pick-datetime для выбора даты. на developer mod (ng serve) все ок. но на prod mod (ng build --prod) выдаеться такая ошибка TypeError: this._document.createElement is not a function при нажации на input

Comment: наверное потому что нужно определить  this._document. Что это такое как Вы его инициализируете?